# Rails checkbox with Ajax submit routing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, form-for

I'm trying to build a re-usable RSVP website for my wife and I, and I'm using it to learn Ruby on Rails (ruby 2.2.2, rails 5.0.0.1), so if you see other things that will cause me problems down the road please don't hesitate to criticize.  A lot of what's in here is from other answers I've been scouring all day.

**The Problem**

The index page I'm working on lists all of the invited guests within a table, and it is intended to allow the event owner to toggle the guest_status (boolean) of a guest with a checkbox using remote: true and an onClick event.  I cannot get the checkbox to submit the correct parameters to the database though, and I'm totally lost on which path to use for the form.  I can't even get the request routed properly so I have no idea what my method is going to do.  I've been trying to solve it myself for around 4 hours and I think I've gotten further from the solution and now I'm making it worse.

**Model relationships**

- Users has_many Events
- Events belongs_to Users
- Events has_many Guests
- Guests belongs_to Events

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :events do
    member do
      get 'rsvp'
    end
    resources :guests do
      member do
        get 'rsvp', only: [:index]
        patch :update_status
      end
    end
  end

  authenticated do
    root to: "events#index", as: :authenticated
  end

  root to: "home_page#static"
end
```

event/:id/rsvp and event/:event_id/guest/:id/rsvp both exist intentionally and will eventually allow non-logged in users to change their guest.guest_status.

**guests_controller.rb**

```
class GuestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :new, :update_status]

  def index
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @guests = @event.guests.all
  end

  def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @guest = @event.guests.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @guest = @event.guests.new(guest_params)
    if @guest.save
      redirect_to event_guests_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Guest.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to event_guests_path
  end

  def update_status #haven't even gotten far enough with routing to test this method
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @guest = @event.guests.find(params[:id]
    )
    respond_to do |format|
      if @guest.update_attributes(params[guest_params])
        format.html { redirect_to event_guests_path, notice: 'Guest updated successfully' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @guest.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private

    def guest_params
      params.require(:guest).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :guest_status)
    end

end
```

**Relevant bits of guests/index.html.erb**

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  . . .

    <% @event.guests.each do |guest| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= guest.first_name + " " + guest.last_name %></td>
      <td>
        <label class="switch">
          <!--<input type="checkbox">
          <div class="slider round"></div>-->
          <%= form_for guest, url: update_status_event_guest_path, :html => { :id => 'guest_status_form' }, remote: true do |f| %>

              <%= f.check_box :guest_status, onchange: "$('#guest_status_form').submit();" %>
            <div class="slider round">
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </label> 
      </td>
      <td>No Response</td>
      <td><%= guest.email %></td>
      <td><%= guest.phone %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', event_guest_path(@event, guest), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>

  <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
```

**edit to add rake routes output**

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                          Controller#Action
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                             devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                             devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                            devise/sessions#destroy
            user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#create
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                        devise/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                       devise/passwords#edit
                          PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#update
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                              devise/registrations#cancel
        user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#create
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                             devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                devise/registrations#edit
                          PATCH  /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#update
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#destroy
               rsvp_event GET    /events/:id/rsvp(.:format)                           events#rsvp
         rsvp_event_guest GET    /events/:event_id/guests/:id/rsvp(.:format)          guests#rsvp {:only=>[:index]}
update_status_event_guest PATCH  /events/:event_id/guests/:id/update_status(.:format) guests#update_status
             event_guests GET    /events/:event_id/guests(.:format)                   guests#index
                          POST   /events/:event_id/guests(.:format)                   guests#create
          new_event_guest GET    /events/:event_id/guests/new(.:format)               guests#new
         edit_event_guest GET    /events/:event_id/guests/:id/edit(.:format)          guests#edit
              event_guest GET    /events/:event_id/guests/:id(.:format)               guests#show
                          PATCH  /events/:event_id/guests/:id(.:format)               guests#update
                          PUT    /events/:event_id/guests/:id(.:format)               guests#update
                          DELETE /events/:event_id/guests/:id(.:format)               guests#destroy
                   events GET    /events(.:format)                                    events#index
                          POST   /events(.:format)                                    events#create
                new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                                events#new
               edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)                           events#edit
                    event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                                events#show
                          PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                                events#update
                          PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                                events#update
                          DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                                events#destroy
            authenticated GET    /                                                    events#index
                     root GET    /                                                    home_page#static
```

Comment: Have you run rake routes to determine that your update_status works properly?

Comment: Yes, and the output is what I would expect it to be.  I don't know if that's right or not, though.

`update_status_event_guest PATCH  /events/:event_id/guests/:id/update_status(.:format) guests#update_status`